# Error 400 bad request on $.ajax(), mongoDB purpose

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb

I'm trying to send data via POST request to my localhost via ajax and then put at datas in mongolab DB ! ...

```
data = {'question':'TEST'};
        $.ajax({
            'url':'http://localhost:3000/addquestion',
            'type':'POST',
            'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'data': data,
            'beforeSend': function( xhr ) 
                              {
                                alert( "TEST BEFORE" );
                              },
            'success': function(){ alert('GG'); }, 
            'error': function(xhr, text_status, error_thrown) 
                        {
                            console.log('ERROR! = ', text_status, error_thrown);
                        }
```

But I have an 400 error BAD REQUEST :-/ ... My final data aren't as simple it should be something like this :

```
SON.stringify({"question": q,
               "reponses": { "a":r0 , "b":r1, "c":r2 },
               "vrai":vrai,
               })
```

but well i'm just trying with a string from now n_n

and here is the code which should save dat into mongolab ! :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var url = 'mongodb://login:password@ds051110.mongolab.com:51110/webdb';
mongoose.connect(url);

var questionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    question: String,
});

var Questions = mongoose.model('Questions', questionSchema);

exports.insert = function(req,res,data) {
    var q = new Questions({
        question: data.question,
    });

    q.save(function(err, a){
        if(err) res.json({'Error':'server'});
    res.json({id:a._id});
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> 10.4.1 400 Bad Request
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

Source: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1

Comment: Yeah but it's not helping me a lot ... ^^'